# Mocking EF core computed field in InMemoryDatabase for unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, entity-framework-core, mocking, in-memory-database

In my database I have computed field "FullName" created by EF core using HasComputedColumnSql fluent API and everything is working fine in the app.

However I have some unit tests using InMemory database which are testing some logic using "FullName" column which is null in InMemory database.

Any idea how I can mock computed column behavior in in memory database?

Answer (score 1):

I’m using the following solution:

1. Add even handler for SavingChanges
2. Inside the handler, loop over entities of the type ou have a computed column on
3. Initialize computed value

Example:
Add event handler:

```
dbContext.SavingChanges += OnSaveChanges;
```

In my case, the class name is Ressource end computed property is “FullName” :

```
private void OnSaveChanges(object? sender, SavingChangesEventArgs e)
{
    var dbContext = sender as <your context class>;
    var ressources = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is Ressource).Select(x => x.Entity as Ressource).ToList();
    foreach (var item in ressources)
        item.FullName = item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName;
}
```

Hope it helps.